# How to reset when creating new video editing file?

Tags: edit-mode, video

Whenever I create a new video editing file in Blender 2.8, it already includes a file that I have previously cut and am finished with. How do I get the program to stop including that file and actually give me a brand new clean format?

Answer (score 0):

When you start blender or create a new file, blender opens your [`startup.blend`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/editors/3dview/startup_scene.html).

You can setup blender anyway you want and save the startup file and get the same contents each time you create a new file. You have managed to save your startup.blend after you added the ever present video track.

To set things up the way you want -

- Start blender
- Remove the VSE track (and any other items)
- Go back to the screen layout you want to start with.
- Use - [File->Defaults->Save Startup File](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/interface/window_system/topbar.html#startup-file)